# Reciprocal of function equal to its norm squared

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions

I'm looking for a function $u$ say, multi variable or otherwise, that has the property

$$\frac{1}{u}=\|u\|^2$$

I have a difficult problem I would like to solve by making a substitution with a function that has this property.

Note I mean the standard Archimedean norm or its generalisation to the complex plane or some other $\mathbf{R}^n.$

Does such a function, or one with a similar property, exist?

Comment: $u(x)=1$ satisfies that. What *other* constraints do you have in mind?

Comment: You are taking $\dfrac1u$, so $u$ is real or complex valued?  In that case what is $\|u\|$ supposed to mean, the pointwise absolute value?  Which complex numbers $a$ satisfy $\dfrac1a =|a|^2$?  This implies $a>0$, so $a=|a|$, and $a^3=1$.

Comment: Yes, this is the intended meaning.

Comment: Ideally, a non trivial example would be nice as a start.A periodic, doubly periodic, quasi periodic etc. function would be even better.

Comment: A nontrivial example doesn't exist based on the stated conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant $1$ has this property.  It is the only one.

No non-constant analytic function can be only real valued in any open region.  Just take a point with a non-zero derivative.  There must be some direction that will have an imaginary component.

Comment: Not sure why I didnt just look at the problem instead of asking. Are there any norms for which such a function could exist?

Comment: The OP never says the function must be analytic.

Comment: But btilly didn't say that the function HAD to be. This answer just notes that if you're looking for an analytic one aside from this, you're not gonna find it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that by algebra, taking the absolute value of both sides, you get
$$
\frac{1}{\|u\|} = \|u \|^2
$$
so $\|u\| = 1$.

So: the constant function $1$ seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Not taking absolute values, $u>0$ already, so $u\equiv 1$.

Comment: OK, I should have said "norm"; and even if $u$ is already positive, it's true that $\|u \| = 1$. You may not think that was a good idea, but it was what I wanted to do to get to my answer. :)

Comment: (I prefer "absolute value" to "norm" for a complex number.) Yes it is true.

Comment: And I prefer "modulus. When you write *your* answers, you should use "absolute value", though, and I promise not to complain. Note that nowhere did the OP say that the codomain was the complex plane, so I was just guessing (from the presence of the double-bars) that it was some normed space. And then I picked a particularly simple normed space in which to show an example.:)

Comment: Because of the $\frac1u$ it had to be a codomain where that made sense.  The OP seemed to clarify in comments when asked that $u$ is real or complex valued. (I was not complaining about your terminology; you *did* use absolute values, so how could I?  But I wouldn't anyway.  I put in the parenthetical because the beginning of your response addressed terminology which I had no dispute with.  I tried to make clear that I had no dispute and failed.)

Comment: There can be nonconstant functions $u$ satisfying $\|u\|=1$ everywhere.

Comment: @Greg: yes, indeed, there can. But OP asked for a function that had a certain property; I played with the property long enough to discover something that suggested a possible solution to me (namely the constant function), and then named that function. I didn't claim that $\|u \| = 1$ *implied* that $u = 1$, just that $u = 1$ had that property (and the OP's desired property).

Comment: Fair enough. It's the question that's sloppily stated, not your answer.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Fair enough; I misunderstood your intent, which is awfully easy to do. Apologies.